# boost::lock_guard vs boost::mutex::scoped_lock

Tags: boost, c++11, future-proof

Which is preferred `boost::lock_guard` or `boost::mutex::scoped_lock`?

I'm using Boost.Thread with the hope to move to C++11 threading when it becomes available.

Is `scoped_lock` part of the next c++ standard?

Are the any advantages to prefer one over the other?

---

*NOTE*: I'm aware that `scoped_lock` is just a `typedef` of `lock_guard`.

---

edit: I was wrong `scoped_lock` is **not** a `typedef` of `lock_guard`.  It's a `typedef` of `unique_lock`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Amit is right: `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is a `typedef` for `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>`, not `lock_guard`. `scoped_lock` is not available in C++0x.

Unless you need the flexibility of `unique_lock`, I would use `lock_guard`. It is simpler, and more clearly expresses the intent to limit the lock to a defined scope.

Comment: I have a question regarding this: afaik while in the scope_lock, any call to shared_lock will be blocked. Is this the same for lock_guard?

Answer (score 27):

Not much difference between the two. As per [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), `scoped_lock` is a typedef for `unique_lock<mutex>`. Both of `unique_lock` and `lock_guard` implement RAII-style locking. The difference between  is simply that `unique_lock` has a more complex interface -- it allows to defer lock and call unlock.