# integer producing hex values error

Tags: c++, integer, hex

something weird is happening to my program. I am currently using lots of threads in my program, and will not be feasible to paste everything here.

However this is my problem:

```
int value = 1000;
std::cout << value << std::endl;
//output:  3e8
```

Any idea why is my output 3e8?

Whats the command to fix it back to print decimal values?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You should try to reduce your code to a minimal example that exposes your behavior. As it stands, there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: The value is correct: 0x3E8 = 1000. What is your question?

Comment: Is there any way to fix all your values to print out in hex? then this way i can go find the root of the problem.

Comment: You may use `printf("%x\n", value);` for hex and `printf("%d\n", value);` for dec if you want ad-hoc control over output format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere in your program a call such as:

```
std::cout << std::hex << value;
```

has been used. To revert output to normal (decimal) use:

```
std::cout << std::dec;
```

here is a [relevent link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/dec/) to the different ways numbers can be output on std::cout.

Also, as pointed out in the comments below, the standard method of modifying cout flags safely appears to be the following:

```
ios::fmtflags cout_flag_backup(cout.flags()); // store the current cout flags

cout.flags ( ios::hex ); // change the flags to what you want

cout.flags(cout_flag_backup); // restore cout to its original state
```

[Link to IO base flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/flags/)

---

As stated in the comments below, it would also be wise to point out that when using IO Streams it is a good idea to have some form of synchronisation between the threads and the streams, that is, make sure no two threads can use the same stream at one time.
Doing this will probably also centralise your stream calls, meaning that it will be far easier to debug something such as this in the future.
[Heres an SO question that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332263/synchronizing-std-cout-output-multi-thread)

Comment: Glad I could help, Try searching for any places in your code that have the first line, and add `<< std::dec` after the value, that will fix this issue. Oh and please mark as answer if this was the fix so others will know this has issue has been solved :)

Comment: yeah sure! i could not mark it previously due to time limit. :)

Comment: @downvoter, please give a reason when down voting an answer. I cannot see what could be wrong with this answer but if there is something wrong I would like to know so I can fix it.

Comment: @Serdalis While I certainly don't think it worth a downvote, the answer isn't really complete.  The usual solution is to save the flags before modifying them, and restore them when finished.  (Also, since the OP mentioned threading, it's worth pointing out that using `std::cout` in more than one thread requires synchronization.)

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that technique, seems much more stable than the inline modifications.

Comment: @Serdalis I tend to use both: braces and suspenders, if you want.  Whenever I change any formatting, I save the state and restore it (using RAII).  But unless I'm the sole owner of the code (and so can be sure that the stream is in its default state), I'll explicitly set all of the flags I need.

Answer (score 11):

Some other thread changed the default output radix of the `std::cout` stream to hexadecimal. Note that 1000<sub>10</sub> = 3e8<sub>16</sub>, i.e. `1000 == 0x3e8`.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that another thread has changed the output to hex on cout. I doubt that these streams are thread-safe.

Comment: it doesn't have to be another thread. it's easy enough to do std::hex then forget to do std::dec afterwards to revert it.

Comment: @TomTanner It's not if you do it right.  Anytime you modify any of the flags, you should guard the modification, ensuring that the original values are restored before leaving the block.

Comment: @JamesKanze that was more or less what I was saying. Easy enough to make the mistake

Comment: @TomTanner Question of habit, I guess.  Every place I've worked, it has been standard practice to create an instance of `IOSave` (or whatever the class was known as locally) at the top of any block which did output.  (In a multithreaded environment, this class could also handle locking.  But you have to be careful about implicit locks; it's very easy to get a mutual deadlock.)