# About boost::lock_guard and boost::unique_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, mutex

I was hoping someone could tell me if my understanding on the following 3 locks is correct and possibly add to it. my main concern is speed with minimum overhead.

- `boost::lock_guard`
- `boost::unique_lock`
- `boost::scoped_lock`

`boost::lock_guard` is the lightest kind of a lock and is only shared amongst members of a process. The `unique_lock` is an improved version of lock_guard with more functionality. The  `scoped_lock` allows locking across different processes.The scoped_lock is the heaviest of all locks.Is my understanding correct. The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276805/boostlock-guard-vs-boostmutexscoped-lock) however states that scoped_lock is similar to unique_lock. if so does that mean `scoped_lock` is as heavy as `unique_lock` ?

Comment: Can you clarify which Boost library you're asking about?  The question you linked to is discussing Boost.Thread, but that library doesn't contain a class called `scoped_lock` at the namespace level (only class level typedefs).  You also mention sharing between processes which suggests Boost.Interprocess (which features a class called `scoped_lock` in the `boost::interprocess` namespace).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by heavy is the amount of overhead, then yes scoped_lock is as heavy as unique_lock, because they're the same thing. According to [this](http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/09/uniquelock-when-lockguard-is-not-enough.html), a unique lock has a few more features than lock_guard, at the expense of a bit of overhead.