std::lock_guard constructor with std::defer_lock argument
This question is based on a misreading of the documentation.
I cannot delete it.

std::lock_guard doesn't have a constructor that takes a defer_lock.

Related (Boost libraries) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276805/boostlock-guard-vs-boostmutexscoped-lock

std::lock_guard doesn't have a defer_lock_t overload, it only has an adopt_lock_t overload.
std::lock_guard always takes ownership of the wrapped mutex and unlocks it on destruction.
The only option is to pass std::adopt_lock to tell it to not lock the mutex on construction. The program then has undefined behaviour if the mutex wasn't already locked by the calling thread.

std::lock_guard has 2 constructors: one takes just a mutex, and the other takes a mutex and an object of type std::adopt_lock_t. That's it; there's no constructor that can be called with a std::defer_lock.
As a result, the destructor always releases the lock.
{
std::mutex mtx;
std::lock_guard guard(mtx);
} // mtx unlocked by lock_guard destructor

{
std::mutex mtx;
mtx.lock();
std::lock_guard guard(mtx, std::adopt_lock);
} // mtx unlocked by lock_guard destructor

In that last example, if the code didn't lock the mutex, the behavior of the program would be undefined; the mutex must be locked if you use std::adopt_lock.
